# c++ program suddenly stopped writing to file

Tags: c++, io

I have very little c++ programming experience, and I wrote a quick program to find groups of links in a long link list.

I have been using this program for the last 2 days and it worked fine (I'm guessing inefficiently, but it worked). But suddenly it stopped writing to the file. I made a new file and changed the file name in the program to check for corruption but it still isn't working. I also have an identical program searching through a separate link list, and that program is still working.

Here is the code:
**I've gotten the program to write to the file by checking for strings with a while loop, instead of a for loop**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string STRING;
    std::string findString;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream infile;

    std::cout<<"Find String: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, findString, '\n');

    infile.open("old.rtf");
    std::ofstream returnFile("return.txt");

    int a = 0;
    std::string previousLine = "";

    while(a < 1)
    {
        std::getline(infile, STRING);
        while(STRING != previousLine &&  STRING.find(findString) != std::string::npos)
        {
                    previousLine = STRING;
                    returnFile<<STRING<<"\n";
                    std::cout<<STRING<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    infile.close();
    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling this using g++ on a mac (running mountain lion)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It stopped writing the output to "return.txt"

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit in your question and ninja deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem (with much help from the people who answered!).

In my original question I was using the following code to loop through the list:

```
while(a < 1)
{
    std::getline(infile, STRING);
    if(STRING != previousLine &&  STRING.find(findString) != std::string::npos)
    {
        previousLine = STRING;
        returnFile<<STRING<<'\n';
        std::cout<<STRING<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

I was able to get the program to write to the file by changing the inside if statement to a while statement. Which is below.

```
while(a < 1)
{
    std::getline(infile, STRING);
    while(STRING != previousLine &&  STRING.find(findString) != std::string::npos)
    {
                previousLine = STRING;
                returnFile<<STRING<<"\n";
                std::cout<<STRING<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

In order to fix the next problem that arose (an infinite loop) I changed the code again to:

```
while(!infile.eof())
    {
        std::getline(infile, STRING);
        if(STRING != previousLine &&  STRING.find(findString) != std::string::npos)
        {
            previousLine = STRING;
            returnFile<<STRING<<"\n";
            std::cout<<STRING<<std::endl;
        }
}
```

The inside while statement in the old code was continuously false because it was checking each line in the file for a specific string. The only reason the loop kept going was the outside while loop was never false. To fix that I changed the outside while loop so that it checked for the end of the file, which ended the loop once everything was done.

Thanks again for the answers. Stack Overflow is always very helpful!

Comment: Change the inner `while` back to an `if` : After the first time through the loop, `STRING == previousLine` so it can't possible go round again, surely?

Comment: I'll fix that, Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue might be related with an infinite loop.

```
int a = 0;
std::string previousLine = "";

while(a < 1)
{
    // a needs to be incremented in here or it will loop forever!
}
```

Comment: @ChrisFrank you might just use `while(!infile.eof()) { }` which is true until the end of file, or `while(getline(infile, STRING)) { }`

Comment: I fixed the problem with writing to the file (I'll update the code in my question). But I'm still having a problem with the infinite loop.